# How to replace a grey scaled image with a varied color?

Tags: gimp, color-conversion

I've been using GIMP for years, but am hardly its master.

I am trying to use this photo:
[image: grayscale image]

As you can see, it has a number of shades of grey as well as black. I have a particular color that I'd like to replace the black letters with and then the greys with the same color but changed to be that same value.

Is there a way to make GIMP do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I selected the layer with the image and clicked on Colors->Colorize... I add the HSV values for my color and BAM! it changed it like magic. Was pretty cool.

Comment: This has no effect for me

Comment: @aggregate1166877 As far as I can tell, `Colorize` works in the HSL model, it mostly changes Hue/Saturation, and so has little to none effect on very dark or very light pixels.

Comment: @xenoid That was my conclusion as well. The answer with the highest votes worked for me and should probably be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to create a gradient and use Color>Map>Gradient map. In the simplest cases, just make the foreground color the darkest color you need, keet the BG color white, and use the FG->BG gradient. With FG=#00006f:

[image]